# Dynamic tab menu. Possible to forget last opened tab content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Thank you in advance for your help!

We have created a somewhat complex bootstrap dynamic (via Ajax) tab menu with 700 nested tabs. When loading the page and clicking the first few tabs the load time is only about 1-2 seconds per tab. That is perfect and exactly what we want. However, after clicking more tabs the dynamic load time increases up to 10 seconds or more.

My question, is it possible to only have 1 tab open at a time? In other words, when I click tab A, then click tab B is it possible for the browser to forget what was in Tab A?

The goal is for all tabs to load in 1-2 seconds, avoiding the progressively longer load times.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... it's not clear what you are asking. providing some *sample* code that is pared down to illustrate *just* the problem you are having would be helpful.

Comment: **700** nested tabs! I hope to God you have a good justification for that (not claiming you don't, but maybe a UX rethink wouldn't be a bad thing). I imagine your problem is related to the browser itself slowing down, rather than the response from your server, from the sheer number of JavaScript objects it's having to cope with. Physically removing them from the DOM may help, but as mentioned above, without some sample code we won't be able to help much